# How to disable ASP.NET Core activities but continue endpoints tracing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, open-telemetry

In our application we set our `traceId`. When ASP.NET Core creates its `Activity` it has no children and will never have. And its `Activity` always stands alone in Jaeger because of different `traceId`. We want to somehow remove this `Activities`.

Firstly, I had this code:

```
builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetryTracing(b =>
{
    b
    .SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault().AddService(serviceName: TracingConstants.ApplicationName, serviceVersion: TracingConstants.ApplicationVersion))
    .AddSource(TracingConstants.EndpointsSourceName)
    .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
    .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
    .AddConsoleExporter()
    .AddJaegerExporter()
    ;
});
```

It creates ASP.NET Core `Activities` that i want to remove.

My first try was to remove `.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()`. ASP.NET core `Activities` disappeared but also disappeared `Activities` of endpoints. I thought that `AlwaysOnSampler` can help but it did not.

Next try was to implement `Filter` in `.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()`:

```
builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetryTracing(b =>
{
    b
    .SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault().AddService(serviceName: TracingConstants.ApplicationName, serviceVersion: TracingConstants.ApplicationVersion))
    .AddSource(TracingConstants.EndpointsSourceName)
    .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation(o =>
    {
        o.Filter = context =>
        {
            return context.Request.Path != "/endpoint";
        };
    })
    .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
    .AddConsoleExporter()
    .AddJaegerExporter()
    ;
});
```

But it had same result as just remove `.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()`.

Now I don't know what to try. Please, help.

Sample code that reproduce my problem:

```
using OpenTelemetry.Resources;
using OpenTelemetry.Trace;
using System.Diagnostics;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetryTracing(b =>
{
    b
    .SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault().AddService(serviceName: TracingConstants.ApplicationName, serviceVersion: TracingConstants.ApplicationVersion))
    .AddSource(TracingConstants.EndpointsSourceName)
    .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation(o =>
    {
        o.Filter = context =>
        {
            return context.Request.Path != "/hello";
        };
    })
    .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
    .AddConsoleExporter()
    .AddJaegerExporter()
    ;
});

var app = builder.Build();

var myActivitySource = new ActivitySource(TracingConstants.EndpointsSourceName);

app.MapGet("/hello", () =>
{
    using var activity = myActivitySource.StartActivity("SayHello");
    
    activity?.SetTag("hello", "world");

    return $"Hello, World!";
});

await app.RunAsync();

public static class TracingConstants
{
    public const string ApplicationName = "SampleCode";
    public const string ApplicationVersion = "1.0.0";
    public const string EndpointsSourceName = "Endpoints";
}
```

---

**UPDATE 26.05.2022**

I have found out that `AlwaysOnSampler` can help but I have to set it with `.SetSampler(new AlwaysOnSampler())` instead of `.SetSampler<AlwaysOnSampler>()` as I did in one of my previous tries.

Here is code that turn off ASP.NET Core `Activities` but continue endpoint tracing:

```
using OpenTelemetry.Resources;
using OpenTelemetry.Trace;
using System.Diagnostics;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetryTracing(b =>
{
    b
    .SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault().AddService(serviceName: TracingConstants.ApplicationName, serviceVersion: TracingConstants.ApplicationVersion))
    .AddSource(TracingConstants.EndpointsSourceName)

    // Because of default OpenTelemetry Sampler is ParentBased(root=AlwaysOn) 
    // and we turned off ASP.NET Core Activities (parent Activities 
    // will not be recorded, so will ours by default Sampler), 
    // we need AlwaysOnSampler to record our Activities anyway
    .SetSampler(new AlwaysOnSampler()) 
    .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation(o =>
    {
        o.Filter = context =>
        {
            return context.Request.Path != "/hello";
        };
    })
    .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
    .AddConsoleExporter()
    .AddJaegerExporter()
    ;
});

var app = builder.Build();

var myActivitySource = new ActivitySource(TracingConstants.EndpointsSourceName);

app.MapGet("/hello", () =>
{
    using var activity = myActivitySource.StartActivity("SayHello");

    activity?.SetTag("hello", "world");

    return $"Hello, World!";
});

await app.RunAsync();

public static class TracingConstants
{
    public const string ApplicationName = "SampleCode";
    public const string ApplicationVersion = "1.0.0";
    public const string EndpointsSourceName = "Endpoints";
}
```

Why different overloads of `SetSampler` works differently??

By the way, approach implemented in code above have issues. Because ASP.NET Cores `Activity` will not be recorded and exported, created by my endpoint `Activities` will have invalid `parentSpanId` and Jaeger will show warning. Also I think that trace will be interrupted because one `Activity` (ASP.NET Cores `Activity`) is always lost.

Comment: Try `o.Filter = (context) => !context.Request.Path.ToUriComponent().Contains("hello", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Comment: @FireShock , thanks for answer. This filter works properly, just like mine. ASP.NET Core `Activities` don't be created. But also my `Activities` don't be created. But I need them